# Make bootstrap modal automatically show (and close as it would normally do)

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to show a modal on page load. So far I have managed this with adding "show in":

```
<div class="modal fade in show sso-login" id="login-form" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true" data-keyboard="1">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <img class="small" src="<?php echo $this->asset('/images/jt-logo-small.png'); ?>" style="display: inline;" />
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                </div>
.
.
.
```

However, when I click the close button or click outside the the modal doesn't close as it normally does when the modal is opened normally (via a link, or javascript method)

Also, I'd like to control this within the generated HTML if possible as I want to determine whether or not to automatically show the modal with server-side code (PHP).

Answer (score 0):

you can open the modal whith the javascript api like this

```
('#login-form').modal('show')
```

and then it will work.

Comment: Is it not possible to set in the HTML? As I've done in my example, but without the mentioned side effects. The HTML is generated on the server, so for example, I can pass ?showModal=login in the URL and PHP can read this and set classes to open the modal.

Comment: you can add the class class="modal fade in" to modal  but have to put `onclick = "$('.modal').hide()"` on button close; to make it work. is better put the javascript modal('show')